# How to get frequency value of recorded sound (tone) in java?

Tags: java

I have a WAV file that contain record of different tones. How to get frequency value of sound? Which library can you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [google lightweight musicg API](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/)

It supports the following features:

Current features

- Clap Api - Detect whether the input audio is a clap
- Whistle Api - Detect whether the input audio is a whistle
- Read PCM WAVE Headers
- Read audio data
- Trim the audio data
- Save the edited audio file
- Read amplitude-time domain data
- **Read frequency-time domain data**
- Render audio wave form image (Requires Java 2D & Java Image I/O,
  Android non-compatible)
- Render audio spectrogram image (Requires Java 2D & Java Image I/O,
  Android

  non-compatible)